Implementation of Linear Screw Actuator Control with ros2_control in ROS2
I am currently exploring methods to effectively control a linear screw actuator within ROS2, specifically through the integration of ros2_control. In my current setup, I have established a prismatic joint in Gazebo to facilitate movement between a slide bar and the robot base link, without yet incorporating ros2_control.
Given the scenario where ros2_control is applied, I am seeking expert advice on the optimal procedural steps to successfully operate the linear screw actuator. What configuration steps and considerations should I prioritize to ensure seamless integration and robust control management?
I look forward to insights and recommendations from the community on configuring ros2_control and verifying its functionality in a simulated environment prior to deployment on physical hardware. Your expertise and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

General advice:

Ensure that your simulated joint has the same interface as you would have in your hardware (command as well as state interfaces, i.e., can you command a position or velocity of your actuator?).
Choose a proper controller. What is the use case for your system? are you sending trajectories (action or topic interface) or single points via topic to the hardware? This will influence the choice of the ros2_controller to use.
Develop the control stack in simulation.
Write your hardware component, and switch between simulation and hardware in your URDF.

